# Publish Custom Events to AWS CloudTrail

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am exploring the options of publishing custom events to cloud trail from a lambda (which is providing a sensitive operational functionality). In order to comply with other auditable actions at the management layer which publishes to CloudTrail, we would like to align and publish our custom events also in the cloud trail using its event schema. Current AWS CloudTrail Java SDK doesn't provide such functionality. I would like to check if that is currently possible to publish custom events?
I couldn't find it in examples samples as well.

Any help or pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of 'custom events' in AWS CloudTrail.

CloudTrail records API calls made to AWS. It does not accept external events.

---

**Update 2023:**

If you're using CloudTrail Lake (managed Athena exports of your CloudTrail) you may insert into your CloudTrail Lake.

See: [PutAuditEvents - AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtraildata/latest/APIReference/API_PutAuditEvents.html)

Java docs: [CloudTrailDataClient (AWS SDK for Java - 2.20.75)](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudtraildata/CloudTrailDataClient.html#putAuditEvents)